# App store app rejection for not supporting orientation in iOS 6

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have developed an iPhone app, which supports orientation for OS version upto 5.1. But my app dose not support orientation for iOS 6. So in iOS 6 my app seems to be buggy will the Apple reject the app.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Why does it support it under 5 but not 6?

Comment: They'll probably won't discover it...

Comment: Hi trojanfoe, this app has been developed long back before the release of iOS 6

Comment: You can disable orientation support and submit again!

Answer (score 0):

From their guidelines:

> Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected

If your app seems to be buggy, they probably will reject it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if by any chance your app passes 'the inspection' you should not feel happy about it.

If your app is allready waiting for review you should at least change release time to "developer decides" and please, don't release it.

It's not so hard to implement orientation support for iOS 6.

A nice blog by Mike Foster on this topic can be found here: [iOS 6 Orientation Handling](http://fostah.com/ios/2012/09/27/ios6-orientation-handling.html)

Fix the bugs and resubmit your app.

Buggy app is annoying to use - and you certainly won't profit from all the mad reviews your app will get. And there will be plenty - a lot of users is on iOS 6.x.

**EDIT:**

According to your comment above: *"...this app has been developed long back before the release of iOS 6"* raises some questions: are you asking about

**a)** the app that was developed long time ago but never released

**b)** the new build (update) of the existing app

**c)** the old build that is all ready on the app store for months?

---

**c)** *don't worry*: app that is all ready on the app store is not likely to get banned due to the iOS6.x related bugs: but you should still fix them as soon as possible. Like - yesterday.

**b)** why would one these days try to publish a build that is not compatible with iOS6.x (see point 'a' below)

**a)** if this app was developed a year ago and was not yet published then you really should take 2 extra days (1 for coding, 1 for debugging) to make it iOS6.x compatible.

I'm sorry if this sounds harsh but your question really does not make a lot of sense. If there are bugs and you know it: exterminate them....